# Modifying arrays (returned by getter as e.g. int**) in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, getter

Suppose there is a class:

```
@interface FooBar : NSObject

@property(readonly, getter = _getSpace) int** space;

@end
```

The space property is implemented as follows:

```
@implementation FooBar

int m_space1[256];
int m_space2[256];
int* m_space[2] = { m_space1, m_space2};

-(int **) _getSpace {
    return m_space;
}

@end
```

Is it then legal to alter the int[2][256] array using:

```
FooBar * f = [[FooBar alloc] init];
f.space[1][120] = 0;
```

?

Comment: Note that `m_space1`, `m_space2` and `m_space` will be declared as *global variables*, despite they are inside the `@implementation FooBar`.

Comment: Global? So I will not have separate set of m_space* members per FooBar instance?

Comment: Right. If you need instance variables, put them inside the `@interface { ... }`.

Comment: @Calikin: I've updated my answer to show how to make them ivars, as KennyTM has suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You're returning a pointer, and then modifying a value that's being pointed to. This is perfectly legitimate. If you don't want to allow this then you need to add the appropriate const modifiers to the type.

What's not legitimate is returning a struct and modifying that struct directly.

---

As KennyTM mentioned in the comments, your `m_space{,1,2}` variables are global variables rather than, as you probably intended, instance variables. The simplest way to fix this is to just put an ivar block in your `@implementation`, as in

```
@implementation FooBar {
    int m_space1[256];
    int m_space2[256];
    int* m_space[2] = { m_space1, m_space2 };
}

-(int **) _getSpace {
    return m_space;
}
@end
```

Comment: I'd also say that, while valid, this is an atypical pattern.

Comment: My question was indeed motivated by the similar struct case you mentioned.